# Specified cast is not valid exception when counting records with linq

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm sure this is a pretty simple one, but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere...

i am trying to count rows from a datatable using linq but exception is throwing ("Specified cast is not valid.") as a result of the condition int > 0

```
    countofbacklog = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("status") = "open" _
        AndAlso x.Field(Of String)("generalStatus") = "PMO" _
        AndAlso x.Field(Of Integer?)("income") > 0).Count
    dt.Dispose()
```

Comment: Are you sure the datatable has the specifed datatypes? Also I hope you have `Count()` at the end.

Comment: If the income is nullable (?) , you can't compare 0 and null.  thus the cast exception.  i don't know how to write it in vb.net. but in C# it would be the nullable column ...  nullable.column.HasValue && nullable.column > 0.

Comment: `nullableColumn.HasValue AndAlso nullableColumn.Value > 0`

Comment: OK,  the solution was combination of all of your comments. thank you very much!!

Comment: `dt.Dispose()` doesn't do anything. `Dataset`, `Datatable` are the cases when `IDisposable` was inherited in hierarchy but has no use at all

Comment: i always wondered about this...tnx for the comment! what about setting it to nothing?

Comment: Don't set to nothing. This is why you have GC for. Also, if you want to reach someone with your comment - add @<userName> in your comment or person will not know. I looked at it incidentally. And don't get carried away. Things like Connection, Command, DataReader have big use of IDisposable. Best bet - use `Using` block when coding those

Comment: @T.S thanks again for your helpful comments!